A java 8 fat-JAR file built with mvn pom file has different structure to local '.m2' repository
I have questions to build an executable JAR with all of dependencies targeting Java 8. The end-users are non-developers.
One of features is to show the content of PDF files in ImageView component of JavaFx. Some of images embedded in PDF files are jpeg2000. So, following dependencies are added in pom.xml of the program
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

And classes in ‘.m2’ repository on my computer looks below.

When I run the program in IntelliJ (2024.2.4 community version), it works well. The images (including jpeg2000) in PDF files show to review correctly.
Then I run ‘clean’ and ‘package’ in pom.xml (inside IntelliJ), a fat-JAR file is created. I check the content in the jar file, it looks like below with a different path name.

When I run this executable jar file and load a PDF file which has an jpeg2000 image embedded, an error occurs, the log messages are below.
11/12/2024-09:10:42 ERROR  PDFStreamEngine(935) - Cannot read JPEG2000 image: Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools are not installed
org.apache.pdfbox.filter.MissingImageReaderException: Cannot read JPEG2000 image: Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools are not installed
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.Filter.findImageReader(Filter.java:172) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.JPXFilter.readJPX(JPXFilter.java:123) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.JPXFilter.decode(JPXFilter.java:72) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.Filter.decode(Filter.java:254) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSInputStream.create(COSInputStream.java:73) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createInputStream(COSStream.java:172) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createInputStream(PDStream.java:193) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createInputStream(PDImageXObject.java:895) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.from8bit(SampledImageReader.java:469) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.getRGBImage(SampledImageReader.java:217) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.getImage(PDImageXObject.java:477) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.getImage(PDImageXObject.java:438) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawImage(PageDrawer.java:1248) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:74) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:893) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:531) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:506) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:153) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:286) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:330) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:247) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(PDFRenderer.java:219) ~[CoverSheetCreatorFX_new.jar:?]

This error doesn't occur when running in IntelliJ. I think the build process with pom.xml does something unexpectedly and the different path to com.github.jai-imageio package in the jar is the root-cause.
BTW, Java 8 is used in development environment on my computer.
The 'build' section in pom.xml is below,
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>CoverSheetCreatorFX</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

If my guess is correct, then how could the issue be fixed in pom.xml (or somewhere else)?
Or if my guess is wrong, then what can I do next?

I don't know how you will get your non-developer users to install a compatible obsolete Java 8 runtime, but that is a separate problem for you.

I don't know the cause of your issue, but perhaps you could try the shade plugin, rather than the assembly plugin.

As you're using jai-imageio-core v1.4.0, why not jai-imageio-jpeg2000 v1.4.0?

IntelliJ always executed the program directly by adding the dependencies to class path. The fat jar merges everything together. It is known that some Java code will not work in a fat jar, e.g. all JCE crypto libraries. Also other code that explicitly searches for a JAR file in the class path will fail. Analyze the stack trace in IntelliJ and got to the causing glass. Look on the code how findImageReader works.

You might get more direct assistance if you provide a [mcve] to replicate the issue (and only the issue) through copy and paste with no change or addition.

note a "groupId" in maven is completely unrelated to a "package" in java - looks like you are confusing these two

I've downloaded and inspected the JAR files for the first two dependencies, and quickly saw that both provide implementations for services (loaded through ServiceLoader) in the javax.imageio.spi package. I haven't seen your assembly file, but I'm guessing your not merging these files from META-INF/services but instead only overwriting them (or even worse - ignoring them). That means that you're going to miss some of the necessary provided services. The classes are there but they are not found by ServiceLoader.
Instead of using the assembly plugin I suggest you use the shade plugin. It has support for ServiceLoader files using its ServicesResourceTransformer.
